# Calling a method with return type "void" in same file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've got a simple question.

In Objective-C, when you have a method you want to call, with a return type of `void`, how you you call it from another method?

The way I've been doing it in my application is this:

```
[self nameOfMethod];
```

But that causes Xcode to spit out the following error:

```
Method '-nameOfMethod' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

Though it seems to still be executing.

Am I calling it right, or is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the declaration of `nameOfMethod`. I think it is not the return type causing the error because it is up to the caller to collect the return value or not. So, check whether there is such method exists in your interface (or) check if at all it is an **instance method**. However, every method should have a return type and if method returns nothing, it should return `void` as answers suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’m guessing you haven’t declared `-nameOfMethod` in the class interface and you’re calling it from another method whose implementation precedes the implementation of `-nameOfMethod`, i.e.:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    [self nameOfMethod];
}

- (void)nameOfMethod {
    // …
}
```

When the compiler is parsing `-someMethod` and `-nameOfMethod` hasn’t been declared in the class interface, it generates a warning because it doesn’t know about `-nameOfMethod` yet.

There are essentially two solutions for this. You could reorder the implementation file so that `-nameOfMethod` appears before `-someMethod`, but that’s not always possible. A better solution is to declare `-nameOfMethod` in the class interface. If `-nameOfMethod` is supposed to be called by clients of your class, place it in the corresponding header file. On the other hand, if `-nameOfMethod` is only supposed to be called inside your implementation file, use a class extension. Supposing your class is named `SomeClass`, this is what your header and implementation files would look like:

```
// SomeClass.h
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
    // … instance variables
}

// … external methods
- (void)someMethod;
@end

// SomeClass.m
#import "SomeClass.h"

@interface SomeClass () // this is a class extension
// … internal methods
- (void)nameOfMethod;
@end

@implementation SomeClass
- (void)someMethod {
    [self nameOfMethod];
}

- (void)nameOfMethod {
    // …
}
@end
```

Using class extensions, the order of method implementations won’t matter.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I've seen methods declared in the .h file in code examples, but never realized the significance of doing it.  I'm still getting familiar with this language.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your interface file contains a definition for nameOfMethod - so;

```
-(void) nameOfMethod;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling it correctly, but make sure that the interface for your (void) method is in your .h file.